# operation not permitted windows phone 8 capturedevice

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I have a Windows Phone 8 application which I am updating to add video uploading/taking capabilities. I'm having problem with the part where I'm placing the video file stream on  `IsolatedStorageFileStream`, which throws an unhandled exceptions.

I previously used the simple video taking API (`VideoCaptureDevice` in conjunction to using `FileSink`), and had no problems whatsoever in saving as file to the isolated storage. It was good but our app needs more control over the compression of the video, which is why I shifted using the advanced camera API for video taking, `AudioVideoCaptureDevice`, which uses `IRandomAccessStream` as the stream-backing of the file.

I had no problems with taking the video itself using the advance APIs, ONLY the problem is when the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` used throws an unhandled exception which indicates in the exception object:

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.
```

The exception is thrown whenever I get to open/create an `IsolatedStorageFileStream` file which was already previously used. I tried everything from closing the `IsolatedStorageFileStream`, disposing it and even setting the object to null.

This is the snippet of code for my implementations of video-taking and also the code for obtaining the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` to get an instance of `IRandomAccessStream` to be used for video API (all are in one same class) (The problematic code here is in the StartOptimizedRecord() method which when called another time, ie., when a user tries to re-record a video, causes unhandled exception of `System.IO.IsolatedStorageException` and/or `System.ObjectDisposedException`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using Policelink.Models;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Phone.Media.Capture;
using Microsoft.Devices;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace Policelink.Views
{
    public partial class VideoCapturePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private VideoBrush videoBrush;
        private IsolatedStorageFileStream isoVidFile;
        private EyeWitnessReportVideo reportVideo;

        //static readonly string videoFileName = "video1.mp4";
        string videoFileName = "";
        bool recording = false;
        TimeSpan timeElapsed;

        BitmapImage pauseImage;
        BitmapImage playImage;

        BitmapImage thumbnailImage;
        MemoryStream thumbnailStream;

        private const int maxLength = 60;

        bool playing = false;

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        public VideoCapturePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            pauseImage = new BitmapImage();
            //pauseImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/media-pause.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            var pauseStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/media-pause.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream;
            pauseImage.SetSource(pauseStream);
            playImage = (BitmapImage) PlayPauseButtonImage.Source;
            reportVideo = new EyeWitnessReportVideo();
            GenerateCurrentVideoFileName();
            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed;
        }

        void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleRecordVideo();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            TimeText.Text = timeElapsed.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            if (timeElapsed.TotalSeconds >= maxLength)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                StopOptimizedRecord();
                recording = false;
                ToggleAcceptButton(true);
            }
        }

        void ResetElapsed()
        {
            timeElapsed = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        }

        void StartTimer()
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        void StopTimer()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        private const string VideoFormatExt = ".mp4";

        void GenerateCurrentVideoFileName()
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString();
            videoFileName = timestamp + VideoFormatExt;
            Debug.WriteLine("Timestamp for currentvideo filename: " + timestamp);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            InitializeOptimizedCamera();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            UninitializeOptimizedCamera();
        }


        AudioVideoCaptureDevice vidCaptureDevice;

        async void InitializeOptimizedCamera()
        {
            if (AudioVideoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back))
            {
                var res = GetLowestVideoResolution();
                var resPrev = GetLowestPreviewResolution();
                vidCaptureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, res);
                vidCaptureDevice.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Aac;
                vidCaptureDevice.VideoEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureVideoFormat.H264;
                await vidCaptureDevice.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(resPrev);
                vidCaptureDevice.RecordingFailed += openedCam_RecordingFailed;
                vidCaptureDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += vidCaptureDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable;
                SetCaptureDeviceProperties();

                videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
                videoBrush.SetSource(vidCaptureDevice);
                RecordViewFinder.Fill = videoBrush;

            }
        }

        void vidCaptureDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable(ICameraCaptureDevice sender, object args)
        {

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IRandomAccessStream videoStream;

        async void StartOptimizedRecord()
        {
            if (vidCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                OpenIsoVideoFile();
                await vidCaptureDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(videoStream);

                ResetElapsed();
                StartTimer();

                //thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream();
            }
        }

        void GetStreamFromIsolatedStorageVideoFile()
        {
            using (var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                isoVidFile = isoFile.OpenFile(videoFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                videoStream = (IRandomAccessStream)isoVidFile.AsOutputStream();
            }
        }

        // calling this method also, but unhandled exception still continues..
        void ResetIsoVideoStreamFile()
        {
            if (videoStream != null)
            {
                videoStream.Dispose();
                videoStream = null;
            }
            if (isoVidFile != null)
            {
                isoVidFile.Dispose();
                isoVidFile.Close();
                //isoVidFile = null;
            }
        }

        void OpenIsoVideoFile()
        {
            using (var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isoFile.FileExists(videoFileName))
                {
                    isoFile.DeleteFile(videoFileName);
                }
                // THIS is where the exception starts, on the call of new IsolatedStorageFileStream, when OpenIsoVideoFile() is being called again after first call..
                isoVidFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(videoFileName, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite, isoFile);
                // Codes below commented doesn't work either, throws the same exception as above...
                //ResetIsoVideoStreamFile();
                //isoVidFile = isoFile.CreateFile(videoFileName);
                //isoVidFile = isoFile.OpenFile(videoFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                videoStream = (IRandomAccessStream)isoVidFile.AsOutputStream();
            }
        }
        // attempts to fix the error of the unhandled exception, but this one to no avail...
        void CloseIsoVideoFile()
        {
            if (videoStream != null)
            {
                videoStream.Dispose();
            }
            if (isoVidFile != null)
            {
                isoVidFile.Dispose();
                isoVidFile.Close();
            }
        }

        async void StopOptimizedRecord()
        {
            if (vidCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                StopTimer();
                await vidCaptureDevice.StopRecordingAsync();
                LoadVideoPlayerFromIsoFile();
                TogglePlayPauseButtonVisibility(true);
                TogglePlayPauseButton(true);
            }
        }

        void SetCaptureDeviceProperties()
        {
            if (vidCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                var profile = KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.H264EncodingProfile;
                var level = KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.H264EncodingLevel;
                var profileProp = H264EncoderProfile.Extended;
                var levelProp = H264EncoderLevel.Level1_3;
                vidCaptureDevice.SetProperty(profile, profileProp);
                vidCaptureDevice.SetProperty(level, levelProp);
            }
        }

        void UninitializeOptimizedCamera()
        {
            if (vidCaptureDevice != null)
            {

                vidCaptureDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable -= vidCaptureDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable;
                vidCaptureDevice.RecordingFailed -= openedCam_RecordingFailed;

                vidCaptureDevice.Dispose();

                vidCaptureDevice = null;
                videoBrush = null;

                recording = false;

            }
        }

        void openedCam_RecordingFailed(AudioVideoCaptureDevice sender, CaptureFailedEventArgs args)
        {

        }

        Windows.Foundation.Size GetLowestVideoResolution()
        {
            var camOkay = AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
            var sorted = camOkay.OrderBy(s => s.Width);
            var lowest = sorted.First();
            return lowest;
        }

        Windows.Foundation.Size GetLowestPreviewResolution()
        {
            var res = AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailablePreviewResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
            var sorted = res.OrderBy(s => s.Width);
            return sorted.First();
        }

        void TogglePlayPauseButton(bool play)
        {
            playing = play;
            PlayPauseButtonImage.Source = playing ? playImage : pauseImage;
        }

        void TogglePlayPauseButtonVisibility(bool visible)
        {
            PlayPauseButton.Visibility = visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        void LoadVideoPlayerFromIsoFile()
        {
            if (isoVidFile != null)
            {
                this.RecorderMediaElement.SetSource(isoVidFile);

            }
        }

        private void RecordClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleRecordVideo();
        }

        void ToggleRecordVideo()
        {
            if (!recording)
            {
                ToggleRecordViewFinderAndPreviewDisplay(true);
                TogglePlayPauseButtonVisibility(false);
                ToggleAcceptButton(false);
                StartOptimizedRecord();
                recording = true;
            }
            else
            {
                StopOptimizedRecord();
                recording = false;
                ToggleAcceptButton(true);
                ToggleRecordViewFinderAndPreviewDisplay(false);
                TogglePlayPauseButtonVisibility(true);
                TogglePlayPauseButton(true);
            }
        }
        private void RecorderMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.TogglePlayPauseButton(true);
        }

        private void SaveToGlobal()
        {
            reportVideo.VideoLocalUrl = videoFileName;
            //GetThumbnailFromVideoPreview();
            App.ArgHelper.CurrentTakenVideo = reportVideo;
        }

        private void GetThumbnailFromVideoPreview()
        {
            if (thumbnailStream == null)
            {
                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(this.RecorderMediaElement, null);
                wb.SaveJpeg(thumbnailStream, (int)currentFormat.PixelWidth, (int)currentFormat.PixelHeight, 0, 60);
            }
            reportVideo.Thumbnail = thumbnailStream;
        }

        private void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoStream != null)
            {
                this.RecorderMediaElement.Play();
            }
        }

        private void PlayPauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (playing)
            {
                if (videoStream != null)
                {
                    this.RecorderMediaElement.Play();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RecorderMediaElement.Pause();
            }
            TogglePlayPauseButton(!playing);
        }

        private void ToggleAcceptButton(bool toggle)
        {
            var acceptBtn = this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
            acceptBtn.IsEnabled = toggle;
        }

        private void AcceptClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToGlobal();
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        void ToggleRecordViewFinderAndPreviewDisplay(bool toggleRecordViewFinder)
        {
            this.RecorderMediaElement.Visibility = !toggleRecordViewFinder ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.RecordViewFinder.Visibility = toggleRecordViewFinder ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```